# Subtract 5 hours from a datetime value that is type timestamp with timezone

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am querying a table that has a datetime column and the value is in the format time stamp with time zone.  I've tried doing a `select hour(timestamp,-5) as NTime` and different variants of that, but the furthest I get is an error stating the timestamp is not a valid name/type.  I'm officially going off the deep end on this....

Basically, I just need the new alias column values to be a time stamp that is 5 hours behind the timestamp that is in the original table.  Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: mysql does not have a timestamp with timezone type.  please only tag your actual database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB / MySQL doesn't have a "timestamp with timezone" data type.

DATETIMEs are simple wall time, and TIMESTAMPs are UNIX time_t timestamps (the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00UTC).

You can convert DATETIME values from one time zone to another by with [tz_convert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)().

```
SELECT tz_convert('2022-04-08 21:53', 'America/Chicago', 'UTC')
```

for example.

Or, just to do date arithmetic you can do stuff like this.

```
SELECT '2022-04-08 21:53' - INTERVAL 5 HOUR
```

Comment: The date arithmetic WORKED!!!  Thank you!  I'm sorry, I was wrong, it was a Teradata DB